# Using Cheat Engine to accelerate time in a Flash program

Tags: flash, shockwave, cheat-engine

I have a flash exe file which has a set of inputs and does a simulation for it. The simulation takes real time to execute and takes about a day to complete 1 round. And I need to get large amounts of data from it.

It was made with Macromedia Director 8.5 which Wikipedia says was released in 2001.

I was trying to use Cheat Engine to make the time faster but I am unable to find the address to modify !
I did not know what datatype the time was stored in, so I used "All" in value type and kept tryint ot find the "Increased Value" it was able to shorten the list to ~250 values, but I am unable to shorten it anymore. The only thing I can see in the simulator is the "hh:mm:ss" time format. And a few buttons to pause, play, stop, load variables, etc.

**What I'm trying to do**:

I'm trying to find the time variable, check what increments it, and make it increment faster.

**Things I already tried** (and failed) :

I tried running it in a Virtualbox with accelerated system time (on virtualbox) to get faster data - the flash program still ran in real time.

I tried recreating it's simulation, but I do not know the physics parameters it uses - it is too complex.

Comment: It's not gonna be that easy I dont think.. changing the time could just mean it cuts out sooner (but not simulate/calculate results faster). It could be computer clock based so maybe changing your **actual** O.S system clock (not just VirtualBox time) ahead by few hours after starting the sim might help (does it look it would correct itself? You have it in front of you some of us don't even know its name or what it does exactly so I'm out of mystery guesses here)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment ! So, the exe is not something popularly published. It has a delay of 1/60 seconds somewhere inside (from documentation) and was made in 2002. The processing part I am assuming is negligible, so I should be able to accelerate it. If I change the actual OS System, nothing happens - Again, because it's 1/60 seconds and a Physics engine which checks for collisions etc every 1/60sec, it would reduce accuracy of result.

Answer (score 0):

Cheat Engine has a built in Speed Hack Function, this should be the first thing you try:

[image]

It works on 99% of games.  If that doesn't work for you, then you have a lot of reverse engineering to do.